# Analogy of Trillium Theorm

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I am thinking about, is there analogy beetween 2d and solid geometry about Trillium theorm. (But im intrest in only acute or right triangles)

Trillium theorem in 2d geometry
holds:

Let ABC be triangle, let I be inscribed circle center in triangle triangle $ABC, midpoint on arc AB (on circle with points ABC) which doesn't include point C.

Therefore |AI| = |BI| = |ID|

(and points, A, I, D are on one line)

Is there any generalization of it in solid geomery like,

Let ABCD be a tetrahedron, let I be the inscribed sphere center in tetrahedron ABC, let line IA, meet the sphere which include points A, B, C and D at point E (diffrent than A), do it means, that
|EC| =|BE| = |DE| = |IE|?

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Comment: No, I haven't, I dont have idea how to compare those lenghts, in other ways than just using geogebra.

Comment: What progress have you made using geomebra, since you mention it? You can include that in the question.

Comment: I didn't even draw it because, it was to hard for me, iIreally like 2d geometry but sadly I need to learn solid geometry, that's why i am asking this question here, because I don't have idea how to solve it.